# in single apk, can I use two different admob ad_id?

Tags: java, android, admob

in single apk, can I use two different `admob` ad_id ?

I mean, I have an app, in that app banner ad and interstellar ad is there so could I put ad banner with ad unitid of `admob` account A  and Interstellar ad `unitid` of `admob` account b in single apk?

Answer (score 0):

> in single apk, can I use two different admob ad_id ?

Yes, you can use as many ad unit ids as you want in an app. Also from different accounts.

But, you should refrain from using separate accounts unless you have a valid justification. Google normally does not allow multiple accounts for a single developer.

Comment: i dont think so, this is a valid answer for the given question.

Comment: well now it looks more reasonable answer. :)

Comment: Make sure you won't make your users hate the app because of these ads

Comment: I use someone else's AdMob ads. Can I put other people's AdMob account ads in my app and is there a limit to using different account ads?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 of course, but I recommend you to use one Ad ID(if you only want to use banners, if you want to use banners and interstitial, then use 2 Ad ID.
Thats because if you upload a lot of Apps, and every app has only one Ad ID, you will be able to study your apps and know which one of them is performing the best with eCPM
Thats my suggestion as a Android Developer.

Answer (score 0):

How will you remove one of the admob account when you find out that your app is running on two different account.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31146228)